# getText() in WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, webdriver, gettext

The following is the HTML code:

```
<div id="TITLE" class="text">
<label for="widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="field(TITLE)" id="widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_title">
<div class="error">This field must not be empty</div>
</div>
```

I tried to get the text "This field must not be empty" as follows by using WebDriver with Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='TITLE']/div")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='error']")).getText();
```

But, no text was retrieved. How can I do it? What's the wrong with my code?

Yes, there is a form. HTMl code including form as belows:

```
<form action="http://community.sandbox.no/content/save.do;jsessionid=F2BF733599D8D9F812B89ACBC20D37C5" method="post">
<div id="widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_leftcolumn">
<input type="hidden" value="article" name="articleType">
<input type="hidden" value="published" name="state">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="successUrl">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="articleId">
<input type="hidden" value="http://sandbox.no/community/article/" name="redirect_url">
<input type="hidden" value="113" name="widget_id">
<div id="TITLE" class="text">
<label for="widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="field(TITLE)" id="widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_title">
<div class="error">This field must not be empty</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello khaleda, Is there any form in HTML? Can you please provide HTML code including form?

Comment: Have you tried making it xhtml? Close your <input> elements like this `<input type="text" name="field(TITLE)" id="widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_title" />`. Maybe thats an issue with xpath in selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div[@id='widget_polarisCommunityInput_113_leftcolumn']/div[@id='TITLE']/div")).getText();

Comment: Is there any getValue() method? Can I also use getValue() instead of getText()?

Comment: to get element value you can try this:
String st = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“blahblah“)).getAttribute(“value”);